# C++ SQL Parser to a Table

Tags: c++, sql, database, parsing, tree

I am programming a very simply database from scratch in C++ along with a SQL parser. I have done everything. So if I have an SQL input like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `First Name`="John" AND `Last Name`="Doe"
```

The parser parses this. The problem now is doing something with that information. I need to look into my table and actually find all the records who first name is John and Last name is Doe.

I was thinking I could implement a tree that would have AND as the main node, with `==` as its childs. The left child being the first name and right child being last name. And whenever it's true, push that record into a vector and then print the vector out at the end.

This all sounds fantastic in theory, but I have NO clue how do actually implement this. If I have an if statement like

```
if(record.firstname == "John")
```

How do I dynamically change `==`, maybe it could be `!=`.

Comment: just a small comment. maybe you can find some answers in the SQLite code

Comment: Making a database is hard, even a simple one. One with a dynamic query language is **really** hard.

Comment: More related to your problem, if you haven't made a compiler/interpreter before, this is going to be extra hard.

Comment: @cha It says `sqlite3 allows the user to manually enter and execute SQL commands against an SQLite database`. Can I just get it to run against my code's database.

Comment: no, what I was trying to say is that SQLIte is an open source software. Just check their source for an inspiration (I am not suggesting plagiarism).

Answer (score 7):

What you need is to translate the SQL into a language which can be directly executed. The technical term for this is the "query plan". The query plan is the low-level operations (e.g. index search, join, sort) that the database engine will do, along with how the operations fit together.

Any decent database engine will give you a way to see the query plan. In the case of SQL systems, it's usually called `EXPLAIN`. I would recommend getting your favourite DBMS (if you don't have a favourite, all of the decent open source DBMSes do it, including MySQL and PostgreSQL) and looking at the plans of various queries just to see what sort of operations the "real" systems implement.

I also recommend looking into relational algebra. If you have access to a well-stocked library, any decent textbook on databases will have a section or chapter on it, but asking Google returns quite a few good references. Relational algebra has the advantage that it's both theoretically nice, and has an "obvious" way to implement it using low-level database operations. You may end up modifying it beyond recognition, but this should give you a good start.

So let's look at a basic overview. Read something about relational algebra first, then read on.

The main data structure that you need to implement is the stream of tuples. Each tuple in the stream is different, but they all have the same shape: each field of the tuple has a name and a type. Query operations take one or more streams of tuples (a table, by the way, can be thought of as a stream of tuples) and returns a single stream of tuples.

Consider a basic SQL `SELECT` statement of the form:

```
SELECT fields
FROM table1,table2
WHERE select_conditions, join_conditions
```

Here, `select_conditions` are any conditions such as `gender='F'` or `age > 18`, where a field is compared against a constant. The `join_conditions` are any conditions which match a field from one table against a field from another table. (We'll ignore the case of comparing two fields from the same table for the moment.)

Then a simple query plan might be:

```
s1 := Select(table1, select_conditions_1)
s2 := Select(table2, select_conditions_2)
j := Join(join_conditions, s1, s2)
res := Project(fields, j)
```

The `Select` operation takes a stream of tuples, and returns a stream of tuples with the same shape, with any tuples that don't match the conditions removed. The `Project` operation takes a stream of tuples and returns a stream of tuples of different type; all it does is remove, rearrange or duplicate fields.  Finally, the `Join` operation joins two streams of tuples together, joining any two tuples which match the join conditions. (If you don't know what a database join operation is, you really need to know this. Ask Google, and also look up the Unix "join" command.)

So in this case, `s1` is a stream of tuples which represents the tuples from table 1 which match the select conditions which apply to table 1. It's a similar story for `s2`. The stream `j` is the streams `s1` and `s2` joined according to the join conditions. Finally, you project out only the fields that are mentioned in the query.

Translating SQL to a relational algebra-like intermediate form is actually pretty easy. However, simple translations tend to be extremely inefficient. Here, we implement the select operation by examining every record in the table and just returning those which match. So the query needs to be optimised, based on both the structure of the query, and what information is available in the table.

For example, suppose that `table1` has fields `age` and `gender`, and we have the select conditions `age > 18` and `gender = 'F'`. Further suppose that `table1` has an index (called `table1_age_idx`) on the `age` field, but no index on the `gender` field. Clearly we should use the index. We can do this by splitting the operation into two more basic operations:

```
s1a := IndexSelect(table1_age_idx, age > 18)
s2b := FilterSelect(s1a, gender = 'F')
```

Here, we've split the select operation into two. The first select is implemented using an index query (note that the select is now on the index, not the table!), and the second one can be implemented by filtering the stream, removing any tuple for which `gender` is not `'F'`.

Implementing join can be done in a bunch of ways (sort-merge join and hash join are popular). Which one is best once again depends on the query and the database. Some indexes (e.g. B-tree and friends) return records sorted by key, so if you've already done an `IndexSelect` on a field that you subsequently join on, then a sort-merge join is probably better, since the sort is unnecessary. The same applies if there is an `ORDER BY` clause on a join field.

As you can see, this is where the really clever stuff happens. Real query optimisers use statistics about the size of a table and the likely size of intermediate tuple streams as part of their calculation. It pays to know a thing or two about compilers here.